# Are questions about airport's naming schemes and markings on topic here?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

Following [this comment](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/36783/where-exactly-berlin-brandenburg-airport-is-being-build?noredirect=1#comment95535_36783) and the fact that [corresponding question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/36783/3230) is marked as off-topic, can someone tell me, if questions about airport's internal design, naming schemes and markings are on topic here?

I must say, that I completely disagree with first part of cited topic. I don't think that question about internal airport design or markings are better on Travel.SE. It has nothing to do with travels and it has a lot of to do with aviation, as per my personal opinion.

If majority agrees, that such questions are on topic then, please, unmark [my question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/36783/3230) as off-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It has nothing to do with travels and it has a lot of to do with aviation, as per my personal opinion.

It's your opinion and you're entitled to it, but I'm going to have to disagree in this case: The "markings" you are referring to are landside, and aside from the fact that they're at an airport they have nothing to do with aviation as an activity or field of study.

An equivalent question would be "Why do the barrier ropes at both [Roosevelt Field Mall](http://www.simon.com/mall/roosevelt-field) and [Walt Whitman Shops](http://www.simon.com/mall/walt-whitman-shops) say *Simon Properties* rather than the name of the specific mall?"

The [airport-markings](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airport-markings) tag wasn't really intended for asking about landside markings: It's more intended for the airside markings on runways/taxiways/ramps/hangars/etc.
Some confusion about this is to be expected here since there was no tag wiki providing guidance. I have created one with examples of the kind of markings that tag is generally targeted at.

---

Regarding topicality and [the possible existence of some off-topic questions which have not been closed](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/36783/where-exactly-berlin-brandenburg-airport-is-being-build?noredirect=1#comment95535_36783) please bear in mind that the existence of some off-topic questions does not provide justification for more off-topic questions: This is the classic "speeding defense" (*But officer all those other cars were speeding too!*), and it doesn't really hold up.

Comment: Then maybe let's do some vacuum action here, right? Because, as you can see in the comment to my question, someone mentioned, that there are a lot of similar questions here about nearly exactly the same and not closed as off-topic. Either all or none should be closed then.

Comment: @trejder I would encourage you, and anyone else with adequate reputation, to vote to close any questions you see that are (for want of a better term) questionable: The bulk of the moderation of the site is done by the community and we try not to "mod-hammer" posts. I'm certainly not going to go on a unilateral post-hunt - just because I have a diamond doesn't mean I get to rule by fiat, and if the community ultimately thinks I'm off the mark here it's my view that gets changed, not their consensus :)